# MVC RedirectToRoute in Global asax not working on hybrid site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I recently rebuilt our webforms site as a hybrid mvc3/webforms website, with the newer code being replace with mvc.  In the past, there was some code in the Application_Error method of the global asax file redirecting users to a 404

```
LifespeakExceptions.Log404();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("~/404.aspx");
```

However, when I tried to replace this with a route, it couldn't seem to find it - for example I tried this in the registermvc3routes file

```
routes.MapRoute(
"404", // Route name
"pagenotfound", 
new { controller = "Utilities", action = "Error404Page" }
);
```

and I added this in global asax

```
LifespeakExceptions.Log404();
Response.RedirectToRoute("404");
```

However, it can't seem to find this route, even though I know it exists -- calling it directly correctly works. Could this be because it's a hybrid site?

Comment: Do you have a controller named `UtilitiesController` with a method named `Error404Page()` that can be accessed via `GET`?

Comment: yes -- I made sure this action method was working properly -- typing it into the url bar it resolves correctly.  I have also tried replacing the route and action with the homepage of the site to see if there was an issue specific to the error action method, but that didn't resolve either